# How to ignore symbolic link (to packages) in middleman?

Tags: middleman

In my source directory I have a symlink to packages (packages is in the root of my project)

middleman build should just copy the symlink over to build. No comparison, nothing.
I already tried ignore "/packages" in my config.rb and making the link by hand in build - but MM still compares source/packages and build/packages.

The problem is that packages is very huge so comparing the two dirs takes to long...

[**Update**]

I added

ignore /^packages/.*/
config[:file_watcher_ignore] += [ /^packages(/|$)/ ]

to my config.rb

OK - middleman now ignores the symlink but if I make the same symlink in build "middleman build" deletes the symlink AND it's contents!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the updated question details - make sure to remove the symlink before the build.

Use something like this in your `config.rb`:

```
before_build do |builder|
  builder.run 'rm [symlink path]'
end
```